# jQuery global plugin instantiation

Tags: jquery, jquery-events

I have something like the code below:

```
$('[data-value]').each(function() {
            var $this = $(this);
            $this.val($this.data('value'));
});
```

with

```
<select data-value="14:00">
    <option>12:00</option>
    <option>13:00</option>
    <option>14:00</option>
    <option>15:00</option>
</select>
```

The goal is to easily pre-select the "data-value" in the list.

The code works perfectly except when I add select elements after the page initialization.

For example, this won't work:

```
$('body').append('<select data-value=yellow><option>black</option><option>yellow</option><option>red</option></select>');
```

So how can I make it work even when I add DOM elements after the page initialization ?

Comment: You must simply run this command again after appending to dom.

Comment: I know but I want something more universal. So when I add something to the DOM the code should trigger all by itself. Maybe I should wrap the code around an event on the body or the document but I don't know which one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so you can use something like:

It checks for new select elements and if it finds some without class 'processed' it processes them.

```
function checkNewSelects() {
    $('select').not(".processed").each(function() {
        var $this = $(this);
        $this.val($this.data('value'));
        $this.addClass('processed');
    });
    setTimeout(checkNewSelects, 300);
}
setTimeout(checkNewSelects, 300);
```

Comment: `setInterval` would probably be a better idea.

Comment: @Inkbug Not really. Using setTimeout makes sure that checkNewSelects waits until it finishes one run before executing new one. Using setInterval checking could have been executed multiple times on slower PCs.

Comment: This is a good solution but it checks the page event if nothing new has been appended. I found the 'DOMSubtreeModified' event maybe we can do something with it.

Comment: DOMSubtreeModified doesn't work on Opera and "Note that the DOMSubtreeModified event is buggy in Internet Explorer 9"